# What is the relationship between Esperanto and spiritism?

Tags: culture

I have heard that a large share of Esperanto speakers in Brazil is somehow affiliated to the [spiritism, based on the books of Allan Kardec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_Kardec).

What encourages spiritists to learn Esperanto? How is Esperanto regarded within the spiritist religion? How is its creator Zamenhof regarded?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this source](http://www.oconsolador.com.br/linkfixo/bibliotecavirtual/esperanto/esperanto_movado.pdf), a relationship between Esperanto and spiritism has first been mentioned in an article by J. Camille Chaigneau in 1908 in the journal *"Gabriel Delanne"*. Two other books stress the special role of Esperanto: *"La  Misio  de  Esperanto"* (19.01.40) and *"Esperanto kiel Revelacio"* (19.01.59) by Francisco  Cândido  Xavier who said he received their content as a medium from two different spirits, Emmanuel and Francisco  Valdomiro  Lorenz.

According to this belief, Esperanto has been created to solve a language problem in the (invisible) spirit world.

Answer (score 1):

Many off mainstream movements seem to some degree attracted to Esperanto. The reason might be, that the Esperanto movement is a rather inclusive one with a lot of curious people. Therefore off mainstream people are usually accepted there and taken serious as long as they are tolerant themselves.

This might be valid for Brazilian spiritists you are referring to but it is valid for many other movements or subcultures.

Comment: would veganism be one of such movement?

Comment: I think this answer misses the point about Esperanto being made in the spiritists text (see my answer), is very general and based on assumptions without sources.